# Restrict JDBC connection to Oracle server

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection

I have a oracle server which is our disaster recovery server. When I failover my application from primary site to secondary site, we have a downtime window during which we have to bring up the secondary site. When bringing up the application on the secondary site I am getting below error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

However, when I try to connect from the SQLPLUS it connects successfully with same username and password but it does not work with JDBC. In order to zero on the issue I tried connecting with SQL Developer with same username and password and it shows the same error.

Can somebody please advice what could the setting be on the oracle server which restricts the JDBC connections?

Comment: What mecamism do you use to switch the jdbc connection to standby database? You should use a failover TNS entry if possible so the connection switch is completely transparent to the user.

Comment: there are different hostnames for primary as well as secondary. when you switch over the application on the secondary site connects to the secondary database.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that you're not entering the same username and password in both cases-- the error is pretty self-explanatory.  Either you're not connecting to the server/ service you think you are or the username or password is different or the passwords on the secondary server aren't in sync with those on the production server.  I suppose it's possible as well that one of the two servers is using case-sensitive passwords while the other isn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is the below setting in the oracle database in sqlnet.ora file

SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=12

after commenting the above it worked.